# How to clone a private Github Repository with Git?

Tags: git, github

I want to clone a **private** Github Repo on my Raspberry Pi.

I tried to clone a **private** Github Repo on my Raspberry Pi with Git with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/"user name"/"repo".git
```

What´s the problem? What have I to do?
Thank you!

Comment: Sure, what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the SSH url instead of the HTTPS url in order to clone repositories. The SSH url should start with `git@`.

This also means you should have your SSH keys set up with your raspberry pi able to access them. You can do that by adding your SSH agent to the raspberry pi and then adding the key in.